# keep previously selected value in dropdown jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to keep the same option value selected even after the click on dropdown, but It just keeps on saying undefined. Here is my code:

```js
 var previous_value;
        $(".acc").on('shown.bs.select', function(){previous_value = this.value;}).change(function() {       
                if($('img').is(':visible')){               
                    if(window.confirm('Please save or data is lost')){                   
                        var t = $('.acc option:selected').val()                 
                       alert(t);
                    }else {
                       //code here              
                     }
                    }
                     else {
                      //code here        
                     }                  
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img  class = "<?php echo $i ?>" src="" alt="" height="22" width="30"> <br/>
    
    <label> AD Mgr </label><br/>
                    <select class = "acc"  >
                    <option  value="1" selected>1</option>
                    <option  value="2">2</option>
                    <option  value="3">3</option>
                     </select>
```

Thank you

Comment: Please include all relevant code, including html

Comment: yeah include more code or even better jsfiddle. .acc what is element is this?

Comment: I added some html.

Comment: @LaMars When i run your code i get the value in the alert. what is not working for you?

Comment: to get the value of the element on `shown.bs.select`, use this: `previous_value = $(this).val()`.

Comment: I need to set previous_value to current value so that the dropdown is not changed. The alert works but how should I set it to previous_value so that dropdown is not changed at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with bootstrap so I can't explain this point but, clearly, the issue in your case is that `on('shown.bs.select', ...)` doesn't fire, so `previous_value` remains `undefined`.

Nevertheless the solution to match your need is pretty simple: you must unconditionally set `previous_value` at start.

Here is a modified version of your code, where not only `alert()` shows new and previous values, but also the dropdown remains always unchanged, like you ask for:

```js
var previous_value =
  $(".acc").change(function() {
    if ($('img').is(':visible')) {
      if (window.confirm('Please save or data is lost')) {
        var t = $('.acc option:selected').val();
        alert('New value: ' + t + '\nPrev value: ' + previous_value);
        $(this).find('option[value=' + previous_value + ']').prop({selected: true});
      } else {
        //code here              
      }
    } else {
      //code here        
    }
  })
  .val();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img  class = "<?php echo $i ?>" src="" alt="" height="22" width="30">
<br/>
<label> AD Mgr </label>
<br/>
  <select class="acc">
    <option value="1" selected>1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
```